Is there any implication of drunkenness in "high lonesome" as used in the term "high lonesome sound"?
Wiktionary has the following entry for "high lonesome sound":

high lonesome sound (music) An expressively emotional, powerful and earthy style of musical expression associated mainly with bluegrass, old-time and country music, characterized by unmetered music and use of gapped scales in singing.

I first encountered the term "high lonesome sound" in connection with a 1998 Smithsonian Folkways collection of recordings by Roscoe Holcomb, titled The High Lonesome Sound. Although there are 21 songs on the CD, none of them has "high lonesome" in the title, and as far as I know none of the lyrics contain that phrase either; evidently it's a descriptive term for the way Holcomb sings and plays banjo.
According to Amanda Petrusich, "The Discovery of Roscoe Holcomb and the "High Lonesome Sound," The New Yorker (December 17, 2015), John Cohen of the New Lost City Ramblers coined the term "high lonesome sound" sometime during or after 1959, after he met Holcomb at the latter's home in Daisy, Kentucky, and heard him sing.
More recently, I discovered that "high lonesome" is (or was) a slang or colloquial term in U.S. English, going back to to the late nineteenth century. Here is the entry for "high lonesome" in Dictionary of American Regional English (1991):

high lonesome n
1 A drinking spree or binge, esp one indulged in alone. [Cited occurrences:] 1897 KS Univ. Qrly. (ser B) 6.53, High lonesome: a 'glorious' drunk or spree: as, He goes off on a high lonesome occasionally. 1915 D[ialect] N[otes] 4,184 swVA, High-lonesome... Debauch; spree. 1917 DN 4,380 KS, High lonesome—A drunken spree, without companions. He went on a high lonesome—he drank heavily alone. 1941 Am[erican] Sp[eech] 16.312 NE (as of c1891), Mrs. Hic Heiman ordered Lafe Brown not to give her husbandliquor, but he did and Hic got on a "high lonesome." 1942 Sun (Baltimore MD) 17 Nov 14/2 (Hench Coll.) Jane always knows when Bill is primed for a high lonesome. He starts a quarrel with her, so he'll have an excuse to drown his sorrows. 1960 Criswell Resp to PADS 20 Ozarks, High lonesome... A drunken spree, Pretty common among men even to this day. 1970 DARE (Qu. DD16) To have a drinking bout and get drunk is to go on a ________) Inf TX89, High lonesome.
2 in phr hit the high lonesome: See quot. 1939 FWP ID Lore 241, Hit the high lonesome—to depart, usually in haste; or to set out for an unknown destination.

So DARE offers multiple instances of "high lonesome" in the sense of "solo drunken spree" from Kansas, Virginia, Nebraska, Maryland, the Ozarks of Missouri and Arkansas, and Texas across the years 1897 to 1970; and it offers one instance of "hit the high lonesome" from Idaho in 1939 in the sentence "head out unexpectedly or abruptly for parts unknown."
J.E. Lighter, Random House Historical Dictionary of American Slang (1997) cites an even earlier occurrence:

high lonesome n. Midland & West. a drinking spree. Also fig[urative]. [Earliest cited occurrence:] 1883 Sweet & Knox Mustang 257: He was a cowboy, who, being on a "high lonesome," entered the saloon , and incontinently began discharging his six-shooter at the lamps and mirror behind the bar.

My question is, Does "the high lonesome sound" have any direct historical link to either of the two earlier forms of "high lonesome" noted by DARE—and if so, what is that connection?
Holcomb does have a song called "Moonshiners," which includes these lyrics:

Come on all of you moonshiners and stand all in a row
You look so sad and lonesome, you're lonesome, yes I know

But, again, I don't think he ever uses the term "high lonesome" in his songs.

Interesting question, I don’t have an answer but the following extract may be helpful: From: The High Lonesome Sound Defined: Examining The Music Of Bill Monroe, 1945-1948.  The exact origination of the term is fuzzy at best and the source of many heated scholarly discussions. In contrast to what others have previously said, the music does not sound "high and lonesome" because the singer is singing in the upper register, nor does it sound "high and lonesome" because of intricate rhythmic relationships. Rather, the "high lonesome" sound comes from a detailed ….

… relationship between linear movement in composition, identifiable through the manipulation of third, fifth, and seventh scale degrees, and "driving" rhythmic design, as well as intricate harmonic relationships that can be traced back to early popular and traditional influences.

@Gio — Here’s the whole thesis for that abstract; check out the first couple of pages of Chapter 1.

There are a number of occurrences earlier than 1883 (1875 was the earliest I could find), but that doesn’t really further. I am curious to see your own answer to your question. Until then, I would say that the dots can’t be connected here; the singers don’t sound drunk; high and lonesome are just a couple of coordinate adjectives in front of sound.

@TinfoilHat: I haven't found an answer to my question. Your 1875 Georgia newspaper instance of "high lonesome" is the earliest one I've seen. The earliest ones in the Chronicling America database are from 1878 and 1879. I did find a copy at archive.org of John Cohen's 30-minute film  "The High Lonesome Sound: Kentucky Mountain Music," but neither Cohen nor anyone else in the film explains the origin of the term. The main impression I get from the film is that the music comes from a place that is mountainous and extremely isolated. ...

... Although Cohen may well have heard the expression "high lonesome" in connection with drunken binges, the music his film is about may have no meaningful connection to the earlier slang expression. (This is, of course, assuming that Cohen coined the term "high lonesome sound.")

A less aurally compromised version of Cohen's film than the one I cited above is available at https://archive.org/details/TheHighLonesomeSound1963.

See Remembering The High Lonesome (2003) (Cohen seems pretty ingenuous...) and a better quality The High Lonesome Sound (1963) — both with transcription...

@TinfoilHat: The quality of the version of "The High Lonesome Sound" that you found is much better than the two I dug up. And the documentary about Cohen is great. I am fully convinced that he wasn't making some kind of jokey allusion to the slang sense of "high lonesome" with his  descriptive phrase for Kentucky mountain music. He comes across as a sincere and open-hearted guy who loved the music and respected the people who made it. Thanks for bringing that documentary to my attention!

Regarding "hit the high lonesome" - this is the usage I'm familiar with from my time with the USFS out west. Long, high altitude routes associated with "bad man's trails"  were high lonesomes. Places like the Uinta High Line, and stretches running across the barren rock badlands in the central parts of Western US between the Rockies and the Sierras. https://www.highlonesome100.com/ (sponsored by a distillery, though)

"His professional service included the dustiest trenches as well as the highest offices of natural resource management―culminating with his 1993 appointment as the thirteenth chief of the U.S. Forest Service. His personal adventures spanned hunting rabbits for Mom's skillet to leading pack strings up into the “high lonesome” of western wildernesses." -https://www.amazon.com/Wilderness-Journals-Wandering-High-Lonesome/dp/1940860164
